# backquote vs backtick

Tags: synonyms, terminology, antonyms

What is the difference between  **backquote** and **backtick** .

Really, i search on this issue . And it seems that are the same .

## `

If so , Is it a synonyms ?

Comment: This link may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash

Comment: Personally, I have never heard of them being called backquotes. _Backtick_ is the only term I've heard (as well, of course, as _grave accent_, when it is used as an actual diacritic, rather than as a character with meaning in programming or markup).

Comment: Lisp programmers call them _backquotes_, because they have a use that's related to that of the normal quote (which is the same character as apostrophe).

Comment: I've heard of them as backquotes or backticks interchangeably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two words can be used interchangeably. Which one is common depends on the specific programming language community. In particular, programmers in Lisp and Lisp-like languages (e.g. Scheme) tend to use the word *backquote*, because this is the term used in the Common Lisp specification (and earlier language documents); in Lisp, the use of the backquote character is a variation on the quote character (it allows "unquoting" within the expression), hence the parallel names.

In other language contexts, *backtick* seems to be more common, because the character is not doing a form of quoting (although MySQL's use is similar to quoting).